# What champions are worst at lasthitting under a turret?

Tags: league-of-legends

There were [some discussions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149818/understanding-last-hitting-and-freezing-a-lane) about lane pushing and freezing. One of the aspects is that you can do that in bot/mid lanes against champions who are very bad at lasthitting under the turret.

Which or what champions are worst at lasthitting under turrets?

Comment: Supports and generally heroes that won't do much damage.

Comment: I am more of a dota player, here attack animations count too, since slower attack animations have a harder time too since it takes more timing to hit the creep on the right moment. I believe LoL has different attack annimations/time per hero too.

Answer (score 3):

Every champion is different when it comes to last hitting, and some are easier purely because their AA hits harder then other champions. This doesnt make CSing under tower any easier. And if you don't know the champion well enough it'll make it even harder, specially if you play as Anivia who is super slow and doesnt hit very hard and then try to CS with Orianna who AA hurts and has average AS.

I think it comes down to 3 things;
**Experience**, **Knowledge of Champion**, **Patience**

*Experience* of how a tower works is easy enough, you can get a perfect CS score even under tower if you know how to use the tower to your advantage.

*Knowledge of Champion*, takes time and games. Any champion can be good at last hitting under a tower if you know how much damage your gonna do and when to use that damage.

*Patience* , dont get flustered that your under your tower; calm down think, plan, and click precisely. Use of the S button never hurt either.

Also if your being supported, how well your support can help you last hit under tower can really help. As a support I will typically hit minions to make it easier for my Carry to get last hits, although this only works if your Carry knows what your doing and times their attacks accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**Champions with low base ad/ very low attack animation-

- Kassadin
- LeBlanc
- Karthus
- Fiddlesticks
- Janna
- Cass.

**

Answer (score 0):

Champions with **low base ad** that typically don't run AD runes/masteries or items:

- Karthus
- Vlad
- Fiddles
- Thresh
- TF

Ashe and Varus also have low base AD and may struggle depending on bonus stats and skill with their waveclear mechanisms.

Champions with a slow attack particle speed. There seems to be no list of AA particle speeds currently available, but champions that stand out as bad in this regard are Annie and Fiddles.