# How can I improve my gameplay to carry myself out of Bronze League?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been playing League for years, since season 1. I'm not an amazing player, but I'm not terrible either. I'm attempting to get out of Bronze League in ranked play, but I'm having a very difficult time doing so. I'm very consistent in my games, particuarly when I ADC as Ezreal. My stats for him over 41 ranked games are K6.7\D3.4\A9.0 with a CS of 153.3. Again, while not spectacular I'm not bad at all either.

My issue is the rest of my team, and how I can interact with them or improve my gameplay enough to carry them entirely. I often have players that die upwards to 10 times, often not killing more than 3 players in the game. Now I know kills don't win games, objectives do, and I frequently communicate, attemping to focus our efforts on said objectives.  When people feed like this however, generally opposing players have grown so strong that it becomes extremely difficult to retain map and objective control.

How can I rally my team to play better, and\or improve my gameplay in such a way that it will enable me to carry them entirely if need be?

Generic answers such as 'be more aware', or 'farm better', are useless as these are skills that can always obviously be improved.  I'm looking for more of a social idea or some particular set of skills not previously mentioned that will allow me to rise above the curve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/154697/how-do-i-become-a-better-league-of-legends-player
Also possibly 'Too Broad'

Comment: I don't think "be more aware" and "farm better" are useless. It's possible to solo carry games. This is a bit harder than ADCs, but your win rate will be > 0.5 if you can consistently be ahead of the enemy ADC. I'm assuming your games last 30+ minutes, in which case you can easily get 250 CS. That 100 CS difference works out to be about 2k gold! As for being more aware, you can ping your teammates back from a gank that they might not notice. There's no single miracle potion to get out of Bronze; you just have to improve on everything a bit or one thing a ton.

Comment: Probably the easiest way to do this is to get a friend and duo queue. A friend you can talk to. Via Skype, Teamspeak, or whatever system you choose. Being able to directly communicate with even one teammate can go a long way. Together, you can convince your team to do what's best even if they don't listen to one of you at first. Don't necessarily point out you're premade, this might actually put you in a weird spot.

Comment: @scenia Duo queueing is actually generally perceived to be detrimental to gaining elo, since your team MMR is inflated when you're in a duo. The benefits of voice chat can be reaped with Curse Voice and a little luck.

Comment: @Schism I don't think that applies to bronze 5 though. Especially if your partner knows what he's doing. having 2 decent players can already decide games on that level. Add communication and you got a pretty strong chance. I agree with you on higher levels, but in bronze the benefit of communication is insane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step to becoming a better player in solo queue is to never blame your team. The reason for this is because there is no benefit to it. Instead, focus on parts of YOUR game to improve. The easiest way to do this is to record your games (with software like lolreplay, etc.), play with only one champion (as much as possible) and watch and critique how you play. This will help you identify your weaknesses as a player. For instance, if during the laning phase, you notice that you all-in a lot (some wins/ some loss) - Then you might notice that when you lost, the opponents' jungler was in the area. So, that would identify that your map-awareness is poor, or you need to invest in wards (for example).
In your case, as an ADC, I'd look into why you're getting lots of assists. Could you have turned those into kills with more aggressive play, or a different build? Are you getting your kills stolen? For Ezreal in particular though, I'd say assists are more likely than playing with for example, Caitlin. Either way, by playing one champion and watching your games you'll find something to improve.

But, in general, you'll need to look critically at improving these aspects of your play (each of which could fill an answer themselves):

**Mechanics**

Look at your last hitting and trading. Were there missed opportunities that you could've harassed or zoned your opponent? Or did you miss a lot of CS by attempting to do so? Could you position better? What about map awareness?

**Meta Game and Objectives**

BE the dragon timer. Know when he spawns and warn your team to group to attempt it. Keep track of his respawn too. Do you have these places warded at the right times?

What about your team composition? Did you lack initiate? Was no one peeling for you - and was it because you were out of position, or because of team composition, or poor play by teammates?

What about towers? Do you have easier to take third lvl turrets available, but you go for deeper ones - and why.

**Teamplay**

This part is the hardest, at least for me. Communicating with your team through more than just pings is essential if you're trying to coordinate a lower level team. Saying things like 'I'm going to buy, don't engage.' or 'Let's try to take top turret next.' or 'Dragon spawns in 1 minute - start to group there.' or 'Let's push bottom a bit and then group to bait Baron'  will win you games. Not just during the game, but champ select too - talk about if you're going to invade, or if your team has too little synergy (ex: too many assassins; no tank; no CC; etc.)

The key when reviewing games is to ask the questions. 'What am I doing?' 'Why am I doing it?' Start at a very small level ('What am I doing standing still?') and then move to bigger gameplay decisions ('Why am I going for top turret here?')

Good luck!

Comment: I tried to answer, but this answer only scratches the surface of ways to improve your play. TL;DR for this answer: record and watch your games

Comment: +1 for the 'never blame your team'. Even if you have only a win rate of 52%, you will still eventually get out of your current league. Tis the beauty of the league system as is. Law of Large Numbers would indicate that, if you're better than the majority of people in your league, the skill of your teammates vs your enemies will eventually balance out and you will go up.

Comment: It's more than just that; you can't DO anything to make your next team better - other than improving yourself. Always focus on what you can change, not what you can't.

Comment: Also very true.