# How to rank up in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have been facing a very hard time ranking up in [league of legends](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fleagueoflegends.com%2F&ei=skJLVKCWEaP5mAXPpYLIBA&usg=AFQjCNHkwWwIC6wIlMNlDz8QGmSd8O21Nw). Whenever I play a ranked games some of my teammates always manage to screw the match up. It has absolutely nothing to do with me. The fight starts within the teammates(not me) till it goes so aggressive that someone starts feeding intentionally or leave the game. I tried the to calm them down with a 40 % success ratio. For all the Gold and diamond players out there, Is it normal or I am too unlucky.  I am currently  stuck in Silver division I and seems that there is no way to rank up for me.

Any tips will be sincerely appreciated.
I pray to god that I find good players in matchmaking.

Comment: Since my answer is already quite long and I want to address a part of your question here :

*Is it normal or I am too unlucky*

It is perfectly normal to have bad teammates every now and then, but ultimately, your rank is your responsibility. Even if you are a master at your champion's mechanics and decision making, you will still lose every now and then, but being good definitely helps in 80% of your games.

Comment: @Jutschge Dude, being a better player and ranking up are two different things. what if you are the best player in the world and 2 guys always afk in every single match? Can you still rank up?

Comment: @FormalDevil It's basically the same question but it's worded differently. Also the answers have the same intention which would be giving tips on learning the game in order to climb the ladder. And Leavers are annyoing but they're part of the game and the luck factor.

Comment: See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165359/how-can-i-improve-my-gameplay-to-carry-myself-out-of-bronze-league/165372#165372 for some additional notes. The first take-away here is 'never blame your team'. The only way you can change the skill level of who is on your team is to improve your own skill.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Imma go on and slap you the with truth.

> Whenever I play a ranked games some of my teammates always manage to
> screw the match up. It has absolutely nothing to do with me.

Probably there's a good 20% of those games where you also did mistakes, may it be mechanical,  wrong calls, or attitude amongst team members.

I was Diamond 3 at LoL Philippines, and then I moved to Oceania, and I got Plat 3 in 1 month of being level 30. (I started at Silver 3)

Elo hell is an excuse to blame your teammates for being stuck.

[Watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJ4vPCY11eM). (funny and real)

Once you've accepted some responsibility in the reason why you are in your rank, you can finally set that aside and focus on **how to actually get better**.

I'm not going to give you specific advice, but I will point you to the right directions.

### There are 3 main [skill dimensions](http://cloth5.com/skill-dimensions-jungle-timers-vs-world/) in League :

1. Micro level (champion mechanics, team fights, instincts)
2. Macro level (long-term plans, action-reaction, map awareness)
3. Game Knowledge (champion abilities, map mechanics, respawn times)

In order to master the game, you have to master these 3 dimensions. Some people are good in one aspect, and some in the other. This explains why there are League coaches for worlds teams who are only silver/gold (needs citation), because they may be very good at the macro level and the game knowledge aspects, but they lack the mechanical skill to deliver their decisions well.

Try to assess yourself as to what aspect you need improvement in, and what do you need to focus on.

For myself, I main Thresh (he's the reason I jumped to Diamond), and in the hundreds of games with him, I admit that I still make mechanical mistakes and some wrong calls.

### MAIN a champion and a role

Watch this vid by PhyLoL : [Why Maining a Champion is one of the Best Ways to Get to Diamond 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7tozC65cKk)

For me, this champion was Thresh. Mastering every little nitty bit of Thresh's mechanics, knowing all the possible matchups and how to approach them, knowing how I should build and how I should move depending on my ADC, and all those things.

I also mastered HOW MUCH I can trade. I know which trades I can win, and ones that I can lose, and all of this comes with mastering a single champion.

### If you want to have fun, play. If you want to improve, study THEN play.

YouTube is the nesting grounds for a lot of coaches and general guides for LoL. I would suggest that you spend some of your time watching videos, opening yourself to knowledge you normally wouldn't think of but they're always there, and apply them to your games.

#### Some notable channels I personally like :

[lastshadow9](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWIfnDrWU_Cvc1a8qZribhA) - He provides THE BEST coaching advice I have ever witnessed. Period. See for yourself.

[FoxDrop](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9U_UPJLasfZYZ0icNI0vBg) - Posts specific champion guides every now and then, watch them if you're interested to play that champion. He also posts champion guides for rank climbing - champs and builds that work generally against low elo players, but not as effective with Plat-Diamond players.

[ScrapComputer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUUnWtcuSp6mEFW9L7uTVoA) - He posts **heavy** guides (some of them are even 1 hour long!) about aspects of the game. He digs into the details, and I recommend him very much.

[PhyLol](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCARZJejxRnmQ0m_tU7MgRiA) - Quite similar with FoxDrop. He also posts game breakdowns for Worlds games, so you can analyze what the pro players think and why they arrived at that specific situation.

### Conclusion

I'm not the best (Diamond 3 back then in LoL PH, Plat 1 now in Lol OCE), but I dedicate my time to actually studying League, aside from **just** playing.

I do not go about and saying "*I'm already Diamond. I'm the best in League. I can definitely own you ingame*", but instead, I never stop learning, because when you stop studying, wherever you are, THAT is your personal Elo hell.

---

#### Some good reads :

[Cloth5 Blogs](http://cloth5.com/category/blogs/) - Provides really good insights and analyses on different aspects of League

[The Bronze Escape - GETTING OUT OF ‘ELO HELL’](http://cloth5.com/bronze-escape-getting-elo-hell/)

[5 Key Mistakes that Low Elo players make](https://www.youtube.com/watch_videos?title=Popular%20uploads&feature=c4-overview&type=0&video_ids=xUIqWSq9SIg%2Ctn8OoyPZrho%2C-bohs9D4h2k%2CYCXPM1oAgBI%2CUkEp93whJK0%2CjZnTDOFpOz0%2CJYls8ELmW2o%2CNjbOTSalnkE%2C8OWFtNJ9cR4%2CobJV439tpDI%2CjcJg6MkHGMM%2Ca1B4n6vzWLA&more_url=)

Comment: Your answer has been really helpful with the channels that you have provided. Thank you for that. I will definitely follow what you said. Still I'm wating for more answers.

Comment: No prob. As for me, my turning point was realizing that I do many many mistakes in-game, and then I started analyzing my games afterwards, asking myself, **What could I have done better?**

Comment: This guy is right. I was stuck bronze 4 for over a year. Took two lessons from a diamond, and I was Silver 4 within 3 months. ELO hell is a myth.

Answer (score 2):

If you find that you are losing games because people are bickering, just keep playing games. Over enough games, assuming you are not an intentional feeder or the like, the enemy team has a higher chance of having feeders / ragers.

Mediation over your teammates is fine, but you will find that it doesn't always work. In that case, just ignore the arguing and focus on your own gameplay. Do not tilt.

In every game you play, focus on what mistakes *you* made (and yes, you made mistakes). I'm a firm believer in the notion that there's no such thing as being "stuck"; just the possibility of not playing enough games. If you've already played many, many games, then that's just an indication that you're in the correct rank and will need to improve before ranking up.

Comment: Yeah you are right not playing enough games might be one of the reason.