# What are techniques to keep a lane frozen?

Tags: league-of-legends

The answers to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149818/understanding-last-hitting-and-freezing-a-lane) address **when** it is appropriate to freeze your lane but in practice I am struggling with the **how.** When I'm playing adc I find it hard to keep the lane in one place. If I want to push I will constantly auto attack the minions and throw in a few abilities and if I want my lane to be pushed I will only attack a minion to score the last hit. To keep the minion wave in one place I imagine I would have to exert the same amount of pressure on the lane as my lane opponents (a tricky balance to maintain).

**So are there are techniques, tricks, or rules of thumb to keep in mind when freezing a lane?**

The champions I play most bot lane are Miss Fortune and Ashe so tips specific to those champs would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to freeze a wave, you first need to get it to be pushing to your tower.  Sometimes it happens naturally, and other times you need to force it to happen.

How to cause it to push to your lane:

1) Walk towards the enemy minions so that they begin to clump.

2) **BEFORE** your wave reaches you and the clumped wave, step into the bushes to lose aggro.  The clumped enemies will focus a single minion at a time, whereas your minions will spread out the damage between the front line of minions.

3)  This is the hard part.  You need to be VERY careful about last hitting here.  Only hit them at the last possible moment otherwise you will begin pushing back to the enemy side.

4)  The enemy wave will gradually build up enough to push towards your lane.

Now you need to freeze the lane.

1)  In order to do this, you want to keep at least 5 enemy minions alive at a time without reaching a turret.

2) Once your wave is dead, hold the minion aggro until your next wave reaches.

3) Try to only last hit minions and again make sure you keep at least 5 enemy minions alive.

4) Rinse and repeat.

Comment: +1, I'd like to add that the "keep 5 minions alive" is really tricky and will need experience, also sometimes if the ennemy is freezing close to their tower and your wave is bigger you should push to the maximum by destroying their wave so that your wave gets killed by the turret (your opponent might lose cs) and the next waves will be in the middle, a safer place to freeze.